# Why is my TS-Jest configuration causing VS-Code to open the JS version of files?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, vscode-debugger, ts-jest

Why is my TS-Jest configuration causing VS-Code to open the JS version of files? It will debug the regular TS file but if I enter any imports it loads the JS version. My files are all written as esmodules and I import libraries in the format: `let jobService = await import("jobs-service");`

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "lib": ["ES6"],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "lib": ["ES2019"],
    "noEmit": false,
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules/*", "./js"]
}
```

jest.config.json

```
export default {
  testEnvironment: "node",
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
  transform: {
    "\\s\\.ts$": [
      "ts-jest",
      {
        tsconfig: "tsconfig.json",
        useESM: true,
        diagnostics: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  testMatch: ["**/*.test.{ts,tsx}"],
};
```

Im expecting the VSCode debugger to open the TS version of imported files. When I had my tests as JS files (and my code base as TS files) it would debug the TS files correctly.